# Spring boot applicaton will not stay up

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I created a simple REST Spring boot application.  I see it start, but it immediately shutsdown.  There is no error in log.

Below is the code and the log.

Code:

```
@Controller
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration 
@RequestMapping("userInfo")
public class UserUpdateService
{
    private java.util.logging.Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("UserUpdateService");

    @RequestMapping(value="/{userId}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/xml; charset=utf-8")
    @ResponseBody
    String getUserInfo(@PathVariable String userId)
    {
        String func = "getUserInfo";
        logger.entering("UserUpdateService", func);

        String retval = "";
        return retval;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{userId}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = "application/xml; charset=utf-8")
    @ResponseBody
    String removeUser(@PathVariable String userId)
    {
        String retval = "";
        String func = "removeUser";

        logger.entering("UserUpdateService", func);
        return retval;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/xml; charset=utf-8")
    @ResponseBody
    String addUser(@WebParam (name = "userId")String userId)
    {
        String retval = "";
        String func = "addUser";

        logger.entering("UserUpdateService", func);
        return retval;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(UserUpdateService.class, args);

    }

}
```

Log:

```
    Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: .hotspot_compiler file is present but has been ignored.  Run with -XX:CompileCommandFile=.hotspot_compiler to load the file.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.1.RELEASE)

- Starting UserUpdateService on localhost with PID 950 (/opt/home/vatsan/MicroSvcs started by vzwadmin in /opt/home/vatsan/MicroSvcs/bin)
- Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@128edf2: startup date [Thu Jan 29 18:59:37 EST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
- Started UserUpdateService in 0.812 seconds (JVM running for 1.806)
- Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@128edf2: startup date [Thu Jan 29 18:59:37 EST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
```

Comment: Can you tell me why it will nto start we a web app?  I am using Java 6 along with Spring Framework 4.1.4 and Boot version 1.2.1.

Comment: I also tried to change the port in application.properties file as: server.port=2003
debug=true

Comment: Moved a little ahead.  I fixed the issue with the app just dying.  It was because I was using Java 1.6 but Tomcat embedded verion was 8. I canhed it to 7 via my build file and that started the service.  It now crashes with a very large stack trace.  I will add them in pieces below.

Answer (score 13):

if you are using maven, check out your pom.xml file, then you will find something like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

it should be changed to this instead:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```